# Solr Retuning wrong results- not exact match

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I am querying for the word `RACE` against defined field `subcategory` which is of type `solr.TextField` and I am getting results which have `RACE`,`RACING`,`RACED` words in it, but I need results matching word `RACE` only. Is this the default behavior of `Solr` or am I doing something wrong in the configuration? Kindly suggest.

Note : I didn't put any stopwords or synonyms in their respective text files.

```
 <field name="subcategory" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

 <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            format="wordset"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            format="wordset"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stemming filter in your chain:

```
<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
```

The task of a stemming filter is to reduce words to their common stem, meaning that `race`, `racing`, `racer`, etc. all will be reduced to the same stem (probably `rac`).

If you do not want stemming to be performed, remove the filter from both your index and query chain.

If you *do* want stemming, but only for certain queries, create a duplicated field with the analysis you want, then use `copyField` to index the same content into both fields and query the field without stemming when you don't want stemming to occur.

Comment: I made the required changes in schema.xml accordingly and uploaded to zookeeper and reloaded the cores.Now, do i need to re-index the old documents for this to work ? In other words, do i need to re-index the old documents again after every solr configuration change ?

Comment: Yes, any changes to how documents are indexed will require a reindex (i.e. unless you're only changing the "index" or "multiterm" part of an analysis chain, you'll have to reindex).